# How do I loop through array with js objects and make conditional replacement of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, replace

New to the programming game, I have an array with a small list of js-objects containing responses for personality test questions.

Each response is related to a personality factor, has a question, describes wether this correlates positively or negatively with the factor, and finally the response on a scale from 1-5.

I need to loop through the array and whenever the key positive has a value of 0, I want to flip the response so that a 1 = 5, 2 = 4, 3 = 3, 4 = 2, 5 = 1.

```js
const response = [
  {
    factor: "conscientinous",
    question: "Prepare for things in advance",
    positiv: 1,
    rating: 3,
  },  
{
    factor: "conscientious",
    question: "Let things get into a mess",
    positiv: 0,
    rating: 1,
  },
];
```

I am trying to do this within a functional paradigm and was thinking .map might be a way forward.

Comment: *map* will create a new array with references to the same objects. Why not just use *forEach* like `response.forEach(obj => if (obj.positiv == 0) obj.rating = 6 - obj.rating)`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array with `Array.map()`, and if `positiv` is 0, return a new object by spreading the original object, and getting the new `rating` by substracting the old rating from 6:

```js
const response = [{"factor":"conscientinous","question":"Prepare for things in advance","positiv":1,"rating":3},{"factor":"conscientious","question":"Let things get into a mess","positiv":0,"rating":1}];

const result = response.map(o => o.positive ? o : {
  ...o,
  rating: 6 - o.rating
})

console.log(result);
```